# ReplaceAll in list not working as expected

Tags: list-manipulation

This is my code.

```
lst = {1, 3, 5};
ReplaceAll[lst, lst[[2]] -> {7, 9, 11}];
lst
```

It is supposed to get output `{1, {7, 9, 11}, 5}`

However, it can only get `{1, 3, 5}` instead.

```
lst = {1, 3, 5};
lst[[2]] = {7, 9, 11};
lst
```

But this one above works. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: try `lst = ReplaceAll[lst, lst[[2]] -> {7, 9, 11}];lst`?

Comment: @kglr Great solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way.

```
lst = {1, 3, 5};
ReplacePart[lst, 2 -> {7, 9, 11}]
```

Comment: This does not address the main issue of the question at all. `lst` remains unchanged.

Comment: @Natas  All of the three approach is right, maybe you should clear the variables or exist the Kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it with `Part` rather than any replacement function? Like so:

```
lst = {1, 3, 5};
lst[[2]] = {7, 9, 11}; lst
```

> ```
> {1, {7, 9, 11}, 5}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you didn't store the intermediate result, to check this simply remove the ; in **ReplaceAll** command. You are expecting ReplaceAll to replace *lst* content which it doesn't.

```
lst = {1, 3, 5};
ReplaceAll[lst, lst[[2]] -> {7, 9, 11}]
lst
```

Gives

```
{1, {7, 9, 11}, 5}
{1, 3, 5}
```